# Why my VennDiagram doesn't create a plot?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am trying to make Venn Diagram in R. I am using the same code I used a few months back. It worked that time. But now the code returns 1 and no plot is made.

```
venn.diagram(
  x = list(RPPA_NF2_PTEN_upregulated_synergy, RPPA_PTEN_TP53_upregulated_synergy, RPPA_NF2_TP53_upregulated_synergy),
  category.names = c("NF2_PTEN_up_syn" , " PTEN_TP53_up_syn " , "NF2_TP53_up_syn"),
  filename = 'up_syn_venn_diagram.png',
  output=TRUE,  imagetype="png" ,
  height = 480 , 
  width = 480 , 
  resolution = 300,
  compression = "lzw",
  fill = myCol,
  cat.cex = 0.2,
  cat.fontface = "bold",
  cat.default.pos = "outer",
  cat.pos = c(-27, 27, 135),
  cat.dist = c(0.055, 0.055, 0.085),
  cat.fontfamily = "sans",
  rotation = 1
)
```

The output is:
[1] 1

Edit: Adding in the data provided in comments below

```
RPPA_NF2_PTEN_upregulated_synergy <- c("17","21","22","28","32","33","45","53","69","73","101","105","118","124","132","134","141","148","154","163","177","189","214","223","225","234","247","257","265","266","277","287","295","306","309","310","316","330","334","352","361","367","368","370","386","390","393","394","403","405","410","419","420","432","441","447","473","486","489")
RPPA_PTEN_TP53_upregulated_synergy <- c("10","13","21","22","28","32","33","45","47","95","101","104","105","112","118","124","132","134","141","148","154","156","158","163","177","179","180","184","188","189","198","203","212","214","215","223","225","226","227","234","236","241","257","266","277","285","286","287","289","295","301","306","309","316","328","330","339","361","367","368","370","394","403","410","414","419","420","432","441","447","456","462","486","489")
RPPA_NF2_TP53_upregulated_synergy <- c("22","65","87","124","132","141","154","165","177","225","234","257","266","277","287","295","306","309","310","328","334","367","368","419","420","441","447","473")
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: > RPPA_NF2_PTEN_upregulated_synergy
 [1] "17"  "21"  "22"  "28"  "32"  "33"  "45"  "53"  "69"  "73"  "101" "105" "118" "124" "132"
[16] "134" "141" "148" "154" "163" "177" "189" "214" "223" "225" "234" "247" "257" "265" "266"
[31] "277" "287" "295" "306" "309" "310" "316" "330" "334" "352" "361" "367" "368" "370" "386"
[46] "390" "393" "394" "403" "405" "410" "419" "420" "432" "441" "447" "473" "486" "489"

Comment: > RPPA_PTEN_TP53_upregulated_synergy
 [1] "10"  "13"  "21"  "22"  "28"  "32"  "33"  "45"  "47"  "95"  "101" "104" "105" "112" "118"
[16] "124" "132" "134" "141" "148" "154" "156" "158" "163" "177" "179" "180" "184" "188" "189"
[31] "198" "203" "212" "214" "215" "223" "225" "226" "227" "234" "236" "241" "257" "266" "277"
[46] "285" "286" "287" "289" "295" "301" "306" "309" "316" "328" "330" "339" "361" "367" "368"
[61] "370" "394" "403" "410" "414" "419" "420" "432" "441" "447" "456" "462" "486" "489"

Comment: > RPPA_NF2_TP53_upregulated_synergy
 [1] "22"  "65"  "87"  "124" "132" "141" "154" "165" "177" "225" "234" "257" "266" "277" "287"
[16] "295" "306" "309" "310" "328" "334" "367" "368" "419" "420" "441" "447" "473"

Comment: Hi Quinten, 
Thanks for your response. My dataset is not very big and I have attached it above here. Hope this helps. Please let me know if you need any other info. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Hi @Ab03, could you please share the output of `dput` in your question above?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `myCol` is defined somewhere, your code is creating a Venn plot and saving it into a file called `up_syn_venn_diagram.png`. By default, this function does not draw the diagram into the plot window. You can do that manually by setting `filename` to `NULL` and plotting the object returned:

```
vplot <- venn.diagram(
  x = list(RPPA_NF2_PTEN_upregulated_synergy, RPPA_PTEN_TP53_upregulated_synergy, RPPA_NF2_TP53_upregulated_synergy),
  category.names = c("NF2_PTEN_up_syn" , " PTEN_TP53_up_syn " , "NF2_TP53_up_syn"),
  filename = NULL,
  output=TRUE,  imagetype="png" ,
  height = 480 , 
  width = 480 , 
  resolution = 300,
  compression = "lzw",
  fill = 'red',
  cat.cex = 0.2,
  cat.fontface = "bold",
  cat.default.pos = "outer",
  cat.pos = c(-27, 27, 135),
  cat.dist = c(0.055, 0.055, 0.085),
  cat.fontfamily = "sans",
  rotation = 1
)

grid.draw(vplot)
```